# Update Linq query selecting from two tables?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq

I am trying to translate a sql query to Linq to be called from a command in my C# WPF application. I've tried to use Linqer but the query won't translate. I'm new to Linq and have been reading around. Do you use a Linq 'JOIN' to solve this?

```
update P 
set P.versionid=a.versionid
from tbPublicationArticles P, tbarticles a
where P.articleid=a.articlesid
```

Comment: AFAIK this can't be done "in one step" using default LINQ-to-SQL (or LINQ-to-entities), as you need to fetch the data first, update it and then save it back to the DB...

Comment: You need to write it as a `select`, then loop through the results setting the values. Linq doesn't have an `update` method like you have above.

Comment: var q = 
        from tbPublicationArticles P, tbarticles a 
        join on P.articleid equals a.articlesid p into ps 
        from p in ps 
        update new {Category = c, p.ProductName };

Comment: @BugFreeSolution er, what is that?

Comment: SQL language has a complex collection of data queries including Data Definition Language, Data Manipulation Language, Data Control Language and Queries. Looks like `LINQ` has only the equivalent part of `Queries`. `UPDATE` command is part of ***Data Manipulation Language***.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First get your data, joining the 2 tables together:

```
var results = from p in db.tbPublicationArticles
              join a in db.tbarticles on p.articleid = a.articlesid
              select new { p, a };
```

Now you loop through the results and make the changes you require:

```
foreach(var item in results)
{
    item.p.versionid = item.a.versionid;
}
```

And don't forget to save your changes:

```
db.SaveChanges();
```